# Laravel foreach loop only shows first entry with dd()

Tags: php, laravel, dump, dd

It might be a weird question but I need your help

I might have an array with values.

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $name_user = //condition
    array_push($firstarray, $name_user );
}
```

Let's suppose that **$firstarray** has these values now ( example : 1 ,2 ,3)

Now

```
foreach ($firstarray as $t)
{
    dd($t);       
}
```

It shows me only the first value

Should it work like this ?  I think it has to show the three values.

Comment: Hello @darcy111 try my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it will only display 1 because **dd()** means **Dump and Die**

You're using DD in a loop, during the first loop, you used the **dd()**, after reading the **dd()**, it will kill all the next processes

I suggest you use the **dump()** so you could see all the contents

Comment: hello @darcy111, if it answered your question, kindly mark this answer as the right one, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that Laravel has `dd()` and `dump()`.

**dd()** = dump and die, meaning that it will show *(print/echo)* you the variable but on the same time your script will stop executing when it reach that point on your code.

**dump()** = dump, simply means that it will show the variable you are interested in, your script will continue executing.

For your situation you should do it like so:

```
foreach ($firstarray as $t)
{
   dump($t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"dd" means "Dump and die".
It prints the first value of $firstarray, "t", and then dies without executing the rest of the loop.
You may wanna try with "echo" or "print_r".
Also, you could use var_dump($firstarray) if you are debugging and want to know the values of the array without having to use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach will iterate over your array. Since you're doing **dump and die**, your code will die on first iteration.

If you want to know your array value, you can dump your array outside the loop

```
dd($firstarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dd` is a function to **dump and die** .lets use `var_dump` method to **dump and not die**:

```
 foreach ($firstarray as $t)
{
    var_dump($t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to show the data in a nice view.

```
foreach ($data as $row){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```